# Mean density from a density function $\rho(r)$

Tags: integration, density, mean-field-theory

Let's say I have some mass density function $\rho(r)$ in a sphere of radius $R$. Question is how can a mean density of object be inferred from such density function ? Is it an integral
$$ \int_0^R \rho(r)dr $$

or something completely different ?

Comment: The captured "mass" in a region is the integral of the density over that region, yes.

Comment: I don't need captured mass, but average density over volume instead, when I only have sphere volume and density function $\rho(r)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a mean, you have to normalise by the volume of the region:
$$\bar{\rho}=\frac{\int^R_0\rho(r)r^2\;\text{d}{r}}{\int^R_0r^2\;\text{d}{r}}.$$
Note you need the volume element in each integral, which is $4\pi r^2\;\text{d}r$ for spherical symmetry.

Note the units too - the numerator has units $\rm[density]\times[volume]$ and the denominator has units $\rm[volume]$, so overall we have units of $\rm[density]$, which is good.

Comment: Edited answer - forgot the $4\pi r^2$ part!

Comment: Can denominator be replaced into sphere volume $4/3 \pi R^3$ ? Because when integrating all volume elements I'll get total sphere volume in denominator or not ?

Comment: And when integrated numerator gives total mass captured in sphere volume ?

Comment: Yes to both comments